# accessing instance variable in cocos2d scheduled method crashes

Tags: ios5, cocos2d-iphone

fresh to objC and cocos2d :)

i'm following "learn cocos2d game development with iOS5", in chapter4, there is a "DoodleDrop" game.

define some variable in `GameScene.h` like this

```
@interface GameScene : CCLayer
{
    CCSprite *player;
    CGPoint playerVelocity;
    CCArray *spiders;
    CGSize screenSize;
    int dropedSpidersCount;
    float duration;
}
    + (CCScene *)scene;
@end
```

in `GameScene.m` the `init` method looks like this

```
- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        duration = 4.0;
        [self createPlayer]; 
        [self createSpiders]; // spiders were inited here.
        [self resetSpiders];
        [self schedule:@selector(chooseSpider:) interval:0.7];
    }
    return self;
}
```

while in `chooseSpider`, i cannot access `spiders`, xcode broke

[image]

in other methods, `spiders` or `duration` just behave normally, why does this happens?

---

**gist code added**

https://gist.github.com/2940466

Comment: does it happen already the first time you call chooseSpider? could you post `createSpiders` code?

Comment: @sergio just logged before [self schedule:...], the `spiders` are ok. `NSLog(@"%d", [spiders count]);` output is 10.

Comment: In the book the spiders array is alloc'd & init'd:
 spiders = [[CCArray alloc] initWithCapacity:spiderCount];

Comment: Btw, spiders is an instance variable of the GameScene class, not a global variable.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D thanks for your explanation. you are right, i missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inspecting your code, I suggest you to try this fix:

```
- (void)createSpiders
{
CCSprite *tempSpider = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"spider.png"];
CGSize spiderSize = [tempSpider texture].contentSize;
int spiderCount = screenSize.width / spiderSize.width;
spiders = [[CCArray arrayWithCapacity:spiderCount] retain];

for (int i = 0; i < spiderCount; i++) {
    CCSprite *spider = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"spider.png"];
    [self addChild:spider];
    [spiders addObject:spider];
}
}
```

where the only difference is in the line:

```
spiders = [[CCArray arrayWithCapacity:spiderCount] retain];
```

Indeed, if you do not retain you `spiders` object, it will be autoreleased at the next run loop iteration.

OLD ANSWER:

Without seeing more code it is not possible to say exactly what is happening, but it seems that in the interval between creating the spiders and the actual execution of `chooseSpiders`, your `spiders` array gets deallocated.

As a quick try, I would suggest adding:

```
[spiders retain];
```

before calling

```
    [self schedule:@selector(chooseSpider:) interval:0.7];
```

and see wether the crash keeps happening.

if you provide more code, it could be possible to help you further.

Comment: thanks @sergio, it crash again:(     more code is provided in gist.

Comment: what you mean `next run loop`? can i set the spiders as a property like this `@property (nonatomic, retain) CCSprite *spiders` so i can ignore the `retain` section in `CCArray` init?

Comment: yes, you can define a retain property and leave the retain explicitly if you assign throu: self.spiders = [CCArray...]; as to the run loop iteration, it is when the autorelease pool is likely emptied...